# Textpad: Java cannot run with package

Tags: java, classpath, textpad

I tried to compile and run Java 10 file with TextPad, it works nicely until I decide to put the file in a folder and use Package(namespace). It seems to be unable to load classes, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.MyProject.HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MyProject.HelloWorld
```

Is there anything I can do about this? I dont seem to find how it is possible to define the class path in TextPad, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it like this:

```
>javac ./com/MyProject/HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

After the compiling...
From the console, try to specify the java HOME, then the path, then the module and the main class:
For example:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\java.exe" -p C:\Users\User\MyFolder -m com.mymodule/com.MyProject.HelloWorld

Comment: I see. I already set java home to be "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2" from System Environment Variable Settings. What do I need to do from here? To add class path? I am using TextPad, I wonder if anything can be done directly in this editor.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't use TextPad. Also you have to add `\bin` to your java home env variables. Then you can use `java -p <pathToYourFolder> -m <module/package#MainClass>`